# How do I create directories with index numbers?

Tags: linux

I want to make directories `hal-01` to `hal-30` on Linux. Is there a single command that can do this?

Comment: mkdir echo hal-{01..30}

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command: `mkdir hal-{01..30}` (at least if you use a shell that supports this form of string expansions (bash does)).

To explain what it does:

```
$ echo {01..30}
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

As you can see the `{01..30}` got expanded to a number of arguments. This works if your curly braces occur within a string as well:

```
$ echo hal-{01..30}
hal-01 hal-02 hal-03 hal-04 hal-05 hal-06 hal-07 hal-08 hal-09 hal-10 hal-11 hal-12 hal-13 hal-14 hal-15 hal-16 hal-17 hal-18 hal-19 hal-20 hal-21 hal-22 hal-23 hal-24 hal-25 hal-26 hal-27 hal-28 hal-29 hal-30
```

Now mkdir accepts a number of arguments and will create a directory for each one. Thus you get what you asked for if you use `mkdir` rather then `echo`.

Comment: My Problem Solve With shall '# mkdir echo hal-{01..30}' thank's @yankee

Answer (score 2):

Use brace expansion, such as like this:
`mkdir hal-{01..30}`

Comment: that's not a regex.

Comment: That's indeed very true, which is why you should never post without coffee. Corrected.

Comment: My Problem Solve With shall '# mkdir echo hal-{01..30}',

Comment: echo is redundant on that line...

Answer (score 0):

mkdir ~/example/folder{1..30} if you want 30

Comment: This will not create a directory `hal-01` as it was asked for. It creates a directory `hal-1` and counting.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `seq(1)` for this, e.g.:

```
mkdir $(seq --format="~/example/folder/HAL-%02.0f" 1 30)
```

Can do other stuff, like different steps and so on. For some unscrutable reason, it computes with floats (!?), the `printf(3)`-like format has to be adjusted accordingly. This works even with plain shells that don't do funky expansions.